# How to prevent duplicates in one to many relation using Java and JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to make a contact program, in which every person is listed with their emails. As you know every person can have multiple emails. So for example John Smith has 3 emails.

```
public class OneToManyDB {
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:1521:orcl";
   static final String USER = "user";
   static final String PASS = "pass";
   static final String QUERY = "select prs.person_id, prs.first_name, prs.last_name, pe.email" +
           " from persons prs" +
           " left join person_emails pe on prs.person_id = pe.person_fk" +
           " where prs.person_id = 1";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);
                      
                while(rs.next()){
                   System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getInt("person_id"));
                   System.out.print(", First: " + rs.getString("first_name"));
                   System.out.print(", Last: " + rs.getString("last_name"));
                   System.out.println(", Email: " + rs.getString("email"));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();       
            }
        }
    }
      
}
```

As you can see there is first and last name of the person and his/hers email contacts.
You can also see the problem of listing them. The output is:
[image: program output]

How can this duplication be avoided? I can't find a pure Java solution anywhere, because I can't use Hibernate. Please help!

The output I want to get is 1 record listing all emails with a delimiter or if this is not a best practice in this case, you can tell me another way.

P.S. Here is the data in the person_emails table:
[image: person emails table]

Comment: You should solve this by adding the appropriate constraints on the table in your database to prevent duplicate records from existing. If this is not what you mean, then please be more explicit in what problem you're trying to solve and what result you do expect.

Comment: They are not duplicates.  User 1 has three email address.  Which one do you want?

Comment: The *correct* title should be: "How to Prevent getting N Records in One-to-many Relationship?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they aren't exactly duplicates - their e-mail addresses are different. So the question is: what would you like to return in such a case?

For example, you might choose to return *any* e-mail address; using an aggregate function helps so you'd modify query to e.g.

```
  SELECT prs.person_id,
         prs.first_name,
         prs.last_name,
         MAX (pe.email) email                           --> this
    FROM persons prs LEFT JOIN person_emails pe ON prs.person_id = pe.person_fk
   WHERE prs.person_id = 1
GROUP BY prs.person_id, prs.first_name, prs.last_name   --> this
```

---

Or, you might want to return *all* their e-mail addresses; use `LISTAGG` to do that:

```
  SELECT prs.person_id,
         prs.first_name,
         prs.last_name,
         LISTAGG (pe.email, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) email  --> this
    FROM persons prs LEFT JOIN person_emails pe ON prs.person_id = pe.person_fk
   WHERE prs.person_id = 1
GROUP BY prs.person_id, prs.first_name, prs.last_name                --> this
```

---

I don't think that applying `UNIQUE` constraint on the `PERSON_EMAILS` table is a good option. Heck, most of us use several e-mail addresses (at work, private, yet another private, ...), and so does John Smith.

---

There are other options, but you have to say what you really want.

Comment: so yes the example with **LISTAGG** is great - this is exactly what I want to be displayed in my Java app. Is it the best practise - for example: If I have one more table in DB, called - phone_numbers and I want to list emails **and** phone numbers of the person, shall I continue using LISTAGG?

Comment: I believe so. It just depends on which format you want; I guess that two columns (one for list of someone's e-mail addresses and another for their phone numbers) is the simplest option. Otherwise, you could concatenate two LISTAGG results into a single column. Or, you could even "mix" e-mail addresses with phone numbers ...

Comment: @NewJavaEnthusiast If you accept that LISTAGG does not exist in many database, then go for it.  Otherwise a simple method would be to do two queries.

Comment: @Scary, **Oracle** tag suggests it *is* Oracle, so I guess it is OK after all.

Comment: @ScaryWombat so in my case the database is going to be Oracle for sure. Two queries is certainly the cleaner way (for me) but imagine that I want to expand the project by adding - person_address, person_univercity, etc. That way I think it will be a lot of requests to the database, which I hope to avoid.

Comment: @NewJavaEnthusiast the return value of LISTAGG is VARCHAR2 so you can retrieve it from your [java] `ResultSet` via method `getString`.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes, I agree with your logic and answer.  Just letting the OP know that if he needs to change to mysql or postgresl or something then the function may not exist

Comment: Your comments are great. However I see that LISTAGG is VARCHAR2 - that is kind of a restriction in a case that I want a lot of info to be in that Column - what if a user has 40 emails or even 400 or a thousand?

Comment: Its length is restricted to 4000 characters. In that case, you could switch to XML option but - who has that many e-mail addresses?